# Magento 2.0.10 HOW AND WHERE DO I PERFORM 1. UPDATE ON SAVE 2. REINDEX REQUIRED

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, reindex, index

I have Magento 2.0.10 and have under the Mode columns 9 (all of them) 
UPDATE ON SAVE

and under Status columns  for Product Price -> REINDEX REQUIRED

```
Product EAV for Product Price -> REINDEX REQUIRED
```

HOW AND WHERE DO I PERFORM THE

1. UPDATE ON SAVE
2. REINDEX REQUIRED

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Run below command for indexer from root path.

open command prompt, go to root path and run command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, reindex is handled by cron. Thus you have to ensure your cron is running properly, you can follow the official documentation here to do so: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Also, I reckon you misunderstood two things:

- Update on Save: this is not an action you have to take, this is the reindexing mode of each index, that means the index will be updated on save, you don't have to do anything.
- Reindex required: this is indeed something you need to do. As said above, it should be handled by your cron.

Alternatively, you can do it manually using SH Patel answer or if you don't have SSH access, you can use this small module I developped to do it from the backend: https://github.com/digitalpianism/reindex

Please note that the manual actions are only for dev purposes, once again, your cron should take care of reindexing.